# Why can't they reverse time to fix infinity stones that Thanos destroyed by getting only time stone from the past?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame

After Wanda destroyed the Mind Stone and killed Vision in the process, Thanos used Time Stone to reverse time around them. That brought back Vision and the Mind Stone.

Now, after Thanos destroyed all the stones, can't Avengers get only time stone from the past and reverse time around Thanos to fix the destroyed stones?

Did they just not think of this?

Of course, time-reversed Thanos is a danger but maybe Captain Marvel can fight him like how she did with 2014 Thanos.
The chance of this working out might be less or even none but the chances of Time Heist working was also unknown at the time when the thought of time heist. Doctor Strange never said Time Heist was the right way.

Comment: Doctor Strange wasn't around to say that the Time Heist was the right way, because he got Snapped before it could happen. He confirmed it later during the battle, when he held up a finger to signify that they were indeed in the one timeline he had seen in which Thanos lost.

Comment: Also none of the Avengers is ABLE to use the Time Stone... they aren't sorcerors.

Comment: @F1Krazy That's just what I said.

Comment: @Paulie_D That's what I thought too at first but there were other sorcerers whom Avengers could find in the world(option 1). Also,(option 2) considering Tony could build an electronic version of Infinity Gauntlet aka Nano Gauntlet and be able to use travel through time without the stone sorcery but just science, it was possible he could try it.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it is questionable whether or not this would work. Doctor Strange was unusual even amongst sorcerers for being able to master the Eye of Agamotto, so it is not clear if there is anyone they could turn to who knows how to do it. Reversing time for five whole years also seems like it would be a lot more work than anything we see the stone used for in previous films, where time reversal is limited to a matter of seconds.

Next, this plan still requires them to go through a lot of the work involved in the time heist anyway - build a functioning time machine and go back to claim one Infinity Stone from the past - only to then go off on a new plan which even if it works requires them to then fight Thanos with all six stones. They may simply decide that getting the other five from the past is the simpler option (obviously they end up fighting Thanos anyway, but that wasn't part of the plan).

Finally, totally rewriting history and undoing the Snap wasn't the plan at all. If those five years are erased then that also eliminates everyone born during that time, including Stark's daughter. Iron Man would never agree to this.

Comment: IIRC at that point they didn't even realize that Doctor Strange was still a surgeon and not a sorcerer when they went back in time and were pretty lucky the Ancient One was in New York protecting the Sanctum with the Eye.

Comment: Reversing time before snap(aka rewriting history) was not what I said and of course never an option. Undoing destruction of the infinity stones sometime after snap by Thanos is what I meant. Though risky, fighting Thanos with Cap Marvel would save Widow from dieing to get soul stone.

Comment: @Anutrix they didn't know Black Widow was going to die when they made the plan for the time heist, and they certainly can't know that no one is going to die if they try to fight Thanos when he has all six stones. Even assuming your plan is possible, he could very well kill some of them in the fight or just snap everyone out of existence.

Comment: @Anutrix also, even if they did want to gamble everything on a rematch with Thanos, the Time Stone seems unnecessary when they already have a time machine. They could just jump back to Wakanda and hope things go better this time.